# HP ProBook 4540s (C4Z14EA) problems with wireless

Tags: wireless, hp

I have HP ProBook 4540s(C4Z14EA). But I can't use wireless. And I can't find driver for wlan. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What is the name of the wireless card you have?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, sorted out by installing 13.04, you can do it via Software Centre or [www.ubuntu.com/download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)